# Flash zooms in when users zooms in browser

Tags: flash, firefox, browser, safari, zooming

I have a feature on my site that is having issues on browsers that have the page zoomed in.  When someone that wants to see the text larger zooms in the page with the browser, it zooms in the flash instead of resizing it, so it makes it unusable.  Is there a way to keep this from happening, or is it just a bug with the browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way browsers are handling page zooming and Flash is resizing the Flash movie and letting it deal with the internals. You need to set either:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Or

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
```

Or

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER;
```

Or

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode. SHOW_ALL;
```

And handle the results inside your application to get the desired result.